# Vue.js: loop on <i18n> tag

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I am using Nuxt.js in static mode to generate my web site, and recently added an i18n module `(nuxt-i18n)` to support the multi-language ability.
Now i want to define translations using custom blocks in my `.vue` files like that, because they page-specific translations:

```
<i18n src="./en.json"></i18n>
```

The problem that when i have 10+ languages it become annoying fast.
My question if there is anyway to generate those tags in a loop, for example `v-for` loop over the `$i18.locales` variable?

Documentation: [nuxt-i18](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/vue-i18n-loader), [vue-i18n-loader](https://github.com/intlify/vue-i18n-loader)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way but definitely not using `v-for` as it is a Vue construct usable only in Vue templates (`<template>` block of SFC processed by Vue template compiler)

[vue-i18n-loader](https://github.com/intlify/vue-i18n-loader) is just extension of `vue-loader` (used for processing `vue` files with Webpack) and works by using it's [Custom blocks](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/custom-blocks.html) and [Src Imports](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/spec.html#src-imports) features. So only ways to solve this is by changing the Webpack build process

Two possible solutions are below. In both cases this adds some complexity into your project so maybe better solution would be to just merge all translations into a single `json` file...

### Option 1 - replace `vue-i18n-loader` with custom solution

Webpack supports importing `json` files by default (they are imported as JS objects)

You can use Webpack's `require.context()` as hinted [here](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/hot-reload.html#advanced-example). Note that you can place the `loadMessages()` function in separate file and import it in your components but you have to pass the context in as parameter because parameters of `require.context` [must be literals](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext)

...in component/page script block

```js
import loadMessages from `@/utils/loadMessages.js`

const messages = loadMessages(require.context('.', false, /\.json$/i))

export default {
  i18n: {
    messages
  }
}
```

Similar solution can be created using [webpack-import-glob-loader](https://github.com/fred104/webpack-import-glob-loader#readme) but it requires to change Webpacks config and merging imported "modules" (JS objects) into single `messages` object...

### Option 2 - Writing custom Webpack loader

It shouldn't be too difficult to write your own loader which would expand something like this `<i18n src="./*.json">` into multiple `<i18n>` sections. Changing Webpack config would be also needed. And your loader has to run before `vue-loader`...